# how do I store these three variables into local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating a mad lib and I can't get my variables to store inside local storage.  I have three variables: noun, nounTwo, and name.  My end goal is once the variables are stored the user will be able to reload the page and the last story they generated will be displayed at the top of the page.

```
    <script>

    function lib() {
    var storyDiv = document.getElementById("story");
    var nounTwo = document.getElementById("nounTwo").value;
    var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    storyDiv.innerHTML = "One day a " + noun + " attacked a " + nounTwo + ", and was defeated by " + name + "!";
    noun.replace('noun', noun.value);
    noun.replace('nounTwo', nounTwo.value);
    noun.replace('name', name.value);
    }

    var libBtn = document.getElementById('generate');
    libBtn.addEventListener('click', lib);

    localStorage.setItem('noun', noun.value);

    console.log(localStorage);

    </script>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mad Lib Lab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Mad Libs</h1>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <div id="story">
      
    One day a
      
    <input type="text" id="noun" placeholder="noun">
      
    attacked a
      
    <input type="text" id="nounTwo" placeholder="noun">
      
    ,but was defeated by a
      
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Famous Person">!

    <button id="generate">generate</button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to display the last story, you don't need to store all three variables.

Also here, noun doesn't contain either of the string you're searching for (it only contains what you wrote in the noun input):

```
noun.replace('noun', noun.value);
noun.replace('nounTwo', nounTwo.value);
noun.replace('name', name.value);
```

This should do the trick:

```
function lib() {
    var storyDiv = document.getElementById("story");
    var nounTwo = document.getElementById("nounTwo").value;
    var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var story = "One day a " + noun + " attacked a " + nounTwo + ", and was defeated by " + name + "!";
    storyDiv.innerHTML = story;
    localStorage.setItem('laststory', story);
}

var libBtn = document.getElementById('generate');
libBtn.addEventListener('click', lib);

if(localStorage.getItem('laststory')) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('laststory');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33z2m6b1/2/

Comment: Thanks I am so grateful for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You call setItem immediately, when there is nothing in `<input>` yet. addEventListener is non-blocking and placeholder is not accessible via `el.value`.

Put it in a function `saveFunc`, for example, and call it from `lib` or add second button `save` with `saveFunc` as listener.

So

```js
    <script>

    function save() {
        var mapping = {'noun': '#noun', 'name': '#name', 'nounTwo': '#nounTwo'};
        for (key in mapping) { // ↓ I prefer querySelector, that's why ids with # ↑
            localStorage.setItem(key, document.querySelector(mapping[key]).value)
        }

        console.log(localStorage);
    }

    function lib() {
    var storyDiv = document.getElementById("story");
    var nounTwo = document.getElementById("nounTwo").value;
    var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    storyDiv.innerHTML = "One day a " + noun + " attacked a " + nounTwo + ", and was defeated by " + name + "!";
    noun.replace('noun', noun.value);
    noun.replace('nounTwo', nounTwo.value);
    noun.replace('name', name.value);
    save(); // ← here it goes.
    }

    var libBtn = document.getElementById('generate');
    libBtn.addEventListener('click', lib);


    </script>
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mad Lib Lab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Mad Libs</h1>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <div id="story">
      
    One day a
      
    <input type="text" id="noun" placeholder="noun">
      
    attacked a
      
    <input type="text" id="nounTwo" placeholder="noun">
      
    ,but was defeated by a
      
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Famous Person">!

    <button id="generate">generate</button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```